# If the real and imaginary parts $U$ and $V$ of an analytic function $f$ are related by $aU + bV + c = 0$ then find $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b$ are not simultaneously zero. The same question was posted to this site previously, however the hints given in that post to the user seem very different to the method I used. Is my working correct?

Since $f$ is analytic, it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Furthermore since $aU + bV + c = 0$, I have that

$$aU_x + bV_x = 0$$
$$aU_y + bV_y = 0$$

Substituting $U_x = V_y$ into the equations I get

$$aV_y + bV_x = 0$$
$$aU_y + bU_x = 0$$

If I re-arrange a bit, I get $V_x = \frac{-a}{b}V_y$ and $U_x = \frac{-a}{b}U_y$. However if I substitute $V_x = -U_y$ into the very first equation I get

$$aU_x - bU_y = 0$$

Which can be rearranged to $U_x = \frac{b}{a}U_y$. Then $\frac{b}{a}U_y = \frac{-a}{b}U_y$ can only be satisfied if $U_y = 0$, since $a$ and $b$ are given not to be simultaneously zero. Then $U_x = 0$. The argument is exactly the same for $V_x = 0$ and $V_y = 0$.

Then $U$ and $V$ are both constant-valued, and if I set $U = \frac{-c}{2a}$ and $V = \frac{-c}{2b}$ Then the relation $aU + bV + c = 0$ is satisfied. So

$$f =  \frac{-c}{2a} +  i\frac{-c}{2b}$$

Is this correct? If it is, is there a much quicker way to do it?